# `kerl update releases` can't update the Erlang R17 package

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I manage my Erlang/OTP versions with `kerl`, and here I want to install R17 with it, but I can't get it work, I just confused.

```
$ kerl update releases 
Getting the available releases from erlang.org...
The available releases are:
R10B-0 R10B-10 R10B-1a R10B-2 R10B-3 R10B-4 R10B-5 R10B-6 R10B-7 R10B-8 R10B-9 R11B-0 R11B-1 R11B-2 R11B-3 R11B-4 R11B-5 R12B-0 R12B-1 R12B-2 R12B-3 R12B-4 R12B-5 R13A R13B R13B01 R13B02-1 R13B02 R13B03 R13B04 R14A R14B R14B01 R14B02 R14B03 R14B04 R15B R15B01 R15B02 R15B02_with_MSVCR100_installer_fix R15B03-1 R15B03 R16A_RELEASE_CANDIDATE R16B R16B01 R16B02 R16B03-1 R16B03
```

There's no R17 available

Comment: This works for me: `The available releases are:
17.0-rc1 17.0-rc2 17.0 R10B-0 ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an older version of Kerl, and need to download a new version.

The Erlang's version names changed from the style "R16B01-1" to the style "17.0.1", and Kerl needed to be modified because its version regex was filtering out anything that didn't look like an "RXXX" version.